# Rails help can't delete object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a problem. I can't delete kategoris.

Rake routes:

```
       admin_kategoris GET    /admin/kategoris(.:format)               {:action=
>"index", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
                        POST   /admin/kategoris(.:format)              {:action=
>"create", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
     new_admin_kategori GET    /admin/kategoris/new(.:format)          {:action=
>"new", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
    edit_admin_kategori GET    /admin/kategoris/:id/edit(.:format)     {:action=
>"edit", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
         admin_kategori GET    /admin/kategoris/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"show", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
                        PUT    /admin/kategoris/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"update", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
                        DELETE /admin/kategoris/:id(.:format)          {:action=
>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/kategoris"}
```

My kategori index view:

```
<% @kategoris.each do |kategori| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= kategori.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'show', {:action => 'show', :id => kategori.id}, :class => 'action show' %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'edit', {:action => 'edit', :id => kategori.id}, :class => 'action edit' %></td>
    <td><td><%= link_to 'slet', {:action => 'destroy', :id => kategori.id, :method => :delete}, :class => 'action destroy' %></td></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My kategori controller:

```
 def destroy
    @kategori = Kategori.find(params[:id])
    @kategori.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(kategoris_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

My routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
resources :kategoris
end
```

I get following error when I press slet (Delete):

```
Started GET "/admin/kategoris/1?method=destroy" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-05 20:0
8:57 +0100
  Processing by Admin::KategorisController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"method"=>"destroy", "id"=>"1"}
  ←[1m←[36mKategori Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `kategoris`.* FROM `kategoris`
WHERE (`kategoris`.`cached_slug` = '1') LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35mSQL (1.0ms)←[0m  SELECT sluggable_id FROM slugs WHERE ((slugs.sluggab
le_type = 'Kategori' AND slugs.name = '1' AND slugs.sequence = 1))
  ←[1m←[36mKategori Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `kategoris`.* FROM `kategoris`
WHERE (`kategoris`.`id` = 1) LIMIT 1←[0m
Rendered admin/kategoris/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
Completed   in 166ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"ka
tegoris", :id=>#<Kategori id: 1, name: "Elektronik", created_at: "2011-02-17 04:
18:11", updated_at: "2011-02-17 04:18:11", cached_slug: "">}):
    6: </p>
    7:
    8:
    9: <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_kategori_path(@kategori) %> |
    10: <%= link_to 'Back', admin_kategoris_path %>
  app/views/admin/kategoris/show.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_admin_kategoris_show_
html_erb__679400070_47327076__118033797'
  app/controllers/admin/kategoris_controller.rb:18:in `show'

Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (4.0ms)
Rendered C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatc
h/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.erb within rescues/layout (57.0ms)
```

My edit link works.

Comment: What do you see in the Rails console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Rails' RESTful actions, the `destroy` method is invoked by a DELETE request (as indicated by the "DELETE" at the beginning of your `rake routes` output), not by a GET request (which is the default unless you specify otherwise). So, you need to specify this in your link:

```
<td><%= link_to 'slet', {:action => 'destroy', :id => kategori.id}, :method => :delete, :class => 'action destroy' %></td>
```

This could be simplified to:

```
<td><%= link_to 'slet', admin_kategori_path(kategori), :method => :delete, :class => 'action destroy' %></td>
```

since `admin_kategori` is a named route that leads to the correct URL, and using the DELETE method will automatically call the `destroy` action (since that's what the routes say to do).

[Update]

It's also possible that you don't have your [UJS](http://www.themodestrubyist.com/2010/02/24/rails-3-ujs-and-csrf-meta-tags/) set up properly. You need to:

1. make sure the `rails.js` script tag (and any libraries it may depend on, like Prototype or jQuery depending on your setup) is included in your layout, and
2. make sure you're outputting `csrf_meta_tag` in the head of your layout. If you're not, it will not work

Comment: The logs show that you're still sending a GET instead of a DELETE request. Can you update the question with your new link code?

Comment: Ah, I think maybe the :method hash should go inside the `url_options` hash (my mistake). Been a while since I haven't used the new RESTful URLs. Try this and let us know if it works: `link_to 'slet', {:action => 'destroy', :id => kategori.id, :method => :delete}, :class => 'action destroy'`

Comment: It's also possible that you don't have your UJS set up properly. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have updated my rails console I get an error now when I press slet. I have the <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

Comment: Then my initial code was correct (the `:method => :delete` goes OUTSIDE the hash with the `:action` and `:id`). If the generated HTML has a `data-method="delete"` attribute, then the problem is that your UJS is not set up properly. Double-check that you're outputting the necessary JavaScript tags in your header.

Comment: Does the generated HTML link tag have the `data-method="delete"` attribute? What is the full output for the 'slet' link? That may help figure out what's going on.

Comment: The output of link: <td><td><a href="/admin/kategoris/10?method=delete" class="action destroy">slet</a></td></td>

Comment: Did you change the `:method => :delete` code to be outside of the hash, as I commented above (undoing the change made in the 4th comment)? `?method=delete` shouldn't be tacked on to the URL; the link should read: `<a href="/admin/kategoris/10" data-method="delete" class="action destroy">slet</a>`. The UJS picks up on the `data-method="delete"` and makes the DELETE call to the server.

Comment: I have moved method outside. Now I get the following output: <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" class="action destroy" href="/admin/kategoris/4">slet</a> But when i press "slet" I get the show action for the kategori

Comment: Then your UJS is not working. :) I'm sorry to keep repeating it, but the UJS driver is solely responsible for converting the GET request into a DELETE via the `data-method` attribute. [Here's the code for the Prototype driver](https://github.com/rails/prototype-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L121-139), as an example. One other option you have is to make a custom route (say, `/admin/kategoris/delete/:id`) that works off a GET request and calls the right action, and then modify your URL.

Comment: What should I do to get the UJS to get working? I have included the <%= csrf_meta_tag %> to the head if my template

Comment: Good question! I've you have the JS *and* the `csrf_meta_tag`, then I'm not positive. If you want to paste the entire HTML output of your page to something like [http://pastie.org/](http://pastie.org/) we can take a look.

Comment: Wow @Brandon, perfect answer and your patience is admirable! @Rails beginner: most likely you are missing the `javascript_include` statement. At least something like `javascript_include :defaults` should be somehwere at the top of your `application.html.erb/haml`. That should include Prototype or jquery, application.js and rails.js. The last one is responsible for the standard behaviour.

Comment: It Works! I did choose the layout in Admin controller and did some few html changes in the layout template.

Comment: Perfect! Glad you got it working, and thanks nathanvda for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

To destroy assets in a REST style formatting, you need to have your http request to be a `DELETE`

Thus you need to add an additional option: `:method => :delete`